# Adding user and group to system - Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to write a short script to add a user to the system with a group and to offer the option to the user to delete a list of users by their name by splitting a string after comma.

```
 #!/bin/bash

    while [ x"$username" = x ]; do

    read -p "Please enter the username you wish to create : " username

    if id -u "$username" >/dev/null 2>&1; then

    echo "User already exists"

    username=""

    fi

    done

    while [ x"$group" = x ]; do

    read -p "Please enter the primary group. If group not exist, it will be created : " group

    if id -g "$group" >/dev/null 2>&1; then

    echo "Group exist"

    else

    groupadd "$group"

    fi

    done

    read -p "Please enter bash [/bin/bash] : " bash

    if [ x"$bash" = x ]; then

    bash="/bin/bash"

    fi

    read -p "Please enter homedir [/home/$username] : " homedir

    if [ x"$homedir" = x ]; then

    homedir="/home/$username"

    fi

    read -p "Please confirm [y/n]" confirm

    if [ "$confirm" = y ]; then

    useradd -g "$group" -s $bash -d $homedir -m $username

    fi

    while [ "$retry" = y ]; do

    retry="n"

    read -p "Do you want to delete users. Enter their username separated by a comma:" users

    if [ x"$users" = x ]; then

    read -p "No user name inserted. Try again? [y/n]" retry

    fi

    done

    IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$users"

    for user in "${array[@]}"
    do
    userdel -r "$user"
    done
```

The problem is when I try to delete the users I get an error of unexpected end of script (without the end the script runs just fine).
Also the new user inserted doesn't appear on the list of system users when I run:

```
for i in $(cat /etc/passwd  | cut -d: -f1); do
   echo -n $i ": "
   grep $i /etc/group | cut -d: -f1 | tr "\n" " "
   echo
done
```

I am a complete begginer when it comes to shell scripting can you please also explain to me where I have mistaken?
Thank you all for your time!
Code checked with http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Why is your script double-spaced?

Comment: `[ x$username = "x" ]` is quoting exactly the wrong thing. `x` doesn't need to be quoted. `"$username"` needs to be quoted. Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds before asking questions here. (And frankly, `[ "$username" = "" ]` or `[ -z "$username" ]` would be clearer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have corrected my script

Comment: As @stark suggests you should [edit] the code to make it more readable by removing the unnecessary extra lines and indenting the contents of loops and conditional expressions.

Comment: Regarding `for i in $(cat /etc/passwd  | cut -d: -f1)` -- see [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). (Also, as a rule, don't read `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group` directly -- depending on how `nsswitch` is configured, there can be users on your system that come from somewhere else; on Linux, if you use `getent passwd` and `getent group`, that'll work no matter what data source your OS is configured to use to track user accounts).